# How to convert AWS sync command using s3cmd

Tags: amazon-web-services, s3cmd

How can I convert the following command and use s3cmd instead?

```
aws s3 sync ./test s3://test --content-encoding "gzip" --content-type "text/html" --cache-control "max-age=0, no-cache" --exclude "*" --include "index.html" --profile stage
```

I want to set the content-encoding, cache-control, content-type, include and exclude tags and profile as I did above.

Comment: s3cmd has a sync command: http://s3tools.org/s3cmd-sync. doesn't it work for your requirement?

Comment: it doesn't allow me to set content-encoding, cache control, exclude, include parameters